# HTML- CSS; add 5px to margin-left for every next nested ul li in hierarchy

Tags: jquery, html, css, treeview

I have nested ul-->li tree, what I want set nested ul padding: 0; margin: 0 0 0 0; and then give margin-left:5px to its parent ul margin. for example at level 1, ul is margin-left:0px then nested ul at level 2 will be (parent ul margin + 5px) which will be 0+5 = 5px; and for nested ul at level 3 will be (5px + 5xp) = 10px;

I prefer to achieve this by css if not then jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/vr84pd6u/7/

### html

```
<div>
<ul class="tree">
    <li><a>System Administration</a></li>
    <li><a>System Core</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a>f2</a></li>
           <li><a>f3</a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a>f4</a></li>
                 <li><a>f5</a></li>
                 <li><a>f6</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a>f7</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a>f8</a>            
                  <ul>
                     <li><a>f10</a>            
                     <ul>
                         <li><a>f11</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                 <li><a>f9</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>MyFunctionA</a>
       <ul>
         <li><a>f12</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a>f13</a></li>
               <li><a>f14</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
          <li><a>f16</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <li><a>Course Management</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

### css

```
 .tree ul li ul {
        border-left: 1px solid #D9DADB;
        background-color: limegreen;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following rules should give you the effect you are after:

```
/*Level 1*/
.tree > li > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*All other levels*/
.tree > li > ul ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

`.tree > li > ul` applies rules to `ul` that are **direct** descendants to `li` which are themselves direct descendants to `.tree`. `.tree > li > ul ul` gets all `ul` which are descendants of the first level `ul`.

Each `ul` in `.tree` that are children to another `ul` will get `5px` left margin, because each `ul` is a child of another `ul` this margin will in effect be stacked.

```css
.tree ul li ul {
    border-left: 1px solid #D9DADB;
    background-color: limegreen;
}
/*Level 1*/
.tree > li > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*All other levels*/
.tree > li > ul ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul class="tree">
        <li><a>System Administration</a></li>
        <li><a>System Core</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a>f2</a></li>
               <li><a>f3</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a>f4</a></li>
                     <li><a>f5</a></li>
                     <li><a>f6</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a>f7</a>
                   <ul>
                      <li><a>f8</a>            
                      <ul>
                         <li><a>f10</a>            
                         <ul>
                             <li><a>f11</a></li>
                         </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                     <li><a>f9</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>MyFunctionA</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a>f12</a>
                <ul>
                   <li><a>f13</a></li>
                   <li><a>f14</a></li>
                </ul>
             </li>
              <li><a>f16</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a>Course Management</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```